How to compute expected gain in lottery where the prize is shared?
Some time ago, I tried to explain to a friend, why it is not a good idea to buy a lottery ticket. I wanted to show that the expected gain is lower than the ticket price, so on average, it is better to keep the money than to buy a ticket. Computing the expected profit should be easy: suppose there are $M$ possible outcomes; when you buy a ticket, you can choose one outcome; if the outcome you chose wins, you get a prize of $T$; otherwise you get nothing. Since there is a $1/M$ chance that the outcome you chose wins, your expected profit is $T/M$.
To my surprise, it turned out that $T/M$ is higher than the ticket price! Initially I could not understand how this can be, as on average, the company running the lottery should be losing money. Then I realized an important point: since each participant can choose the outcome, it is possible (and even likely) that two or more people choose the same outcome. In case the winning outcome is chosen by $k$ people, the prize of $T$ is shared equally between them, so each one of them gets only $T/k$.
MY QUESTION: what is the actual expected profit in the game I described?
The answer probably depends on the number of participants; Let's say there are $N$ participants.

If you have no information on which outcomes the other participants will choose and therefore assume they will choose randomly among the outcomes, the expected winnings for a player of one ticket are $T/N$ where $N$ is the number of tickets sold.  If there are many more participants than outcomes it is almost certain that the prize will be shared.  If ta ticket costs $p$,The operator is showing a profit of $Np-T$ before expenses, so if they sell enough tickets they will do well.  The expected profit to the ticket buyer is then $T/N-p$
If you believe one of the outcomes will be unpopular buying one of those tickets has an advantage over buying the others.  If it is unpopular enough it might be a winning bet.  If the outcome wins the payoff will be $T/k$ where $k$ is the number of tickets bought on that outcome.

"the expected winnings for a player of one ticket are T/N where N is the number of tickets sold" - I do not understand why. Note that, since each ticket buyer chooses his own outcome, it is possible that the winning outcome was not chosen by anyone, so nobody wins. It is also possible that two or more tickets win (and share the prize). So why T/N?

I also do not understand why "The operator is showing a profit of N−T before expenses". Do you assume that the price of each ticket is 1?

@ErelSegal-Halevi: yes, I was assuming that.  $N$ should really be the total value of the tickets sold.  I will correct it, but the argument does not change.

I still do not understand why the expected winnings for a player are $T/N$?

Each ticket has an equal chance to win the prize and you are assuming that the same number of tickets have chosen each option.  In that case all the tickets have the same expectation.  The sum of the expectations of the $N$ tickets is $T$
